# Required Field in Windows phone application 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a simple Windows phone application.in my application a login form is created also password field sets as required field.
I'm following this tutorial,
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/72d20e/create-login-and-registration-form-in-windows-phone-7/? 
But I didn't know how to display "*" near the password text.is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing by "*" you mean blanking out the characters in the textbox for the password. In Windows Phone 8 there is a specialised textbox for this called passwordBox that you should use instead of textbox. Its XAML code should be something like below:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" />
```

**EDIT:**

If you mean showing a star next to the username and password box, then yeah you just need to change the text field of the textblock from 'Password' to "Password *". However I am not to sure why you would want to do this as it should be pretty obvious that you have to enter the password

Comment: If you have selected this answer as correct, could you also please select it as the answer. (Press the tick next to the answer)

Comment: Thank you for your response.i just meant that I want to display * for some required fields in my form.example dob,country etc.like in html we can use "required".is there any field like that?

Answer (score 0):

Your example uses `Margin` to position the `<TextBox>` and `<Button>` vertically and horizontally on the screen.  So to put anything new on the same line as a particular object, you need to use the same `Margin`.

```XAML
<TextBox Height="76" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,111,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
<TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="28,254,0,0" Name="textBox2" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
```

The first TextBox is the User Name it uses a Margin of 28 110 0 0
The second TextBox is the Password it uses a Margin of 28 254 0 0

So to put something before the Password just create a new TextBlock with the same Margin but offset it a little.

```XAML
<!-- this will put a * before the Password TextBox -->
<TextBlock Text="*" Margin="10,254,0,0"/>
```